# Node.js Nested MySQL Queries for Beginner

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have two nested sql queries:

1. SELECT * FROM events
2. SELECT * FROM photos WHERE event = ?

Table events (id, name, description, startDate, endDate)
Table photos (id, name, url, eventId)

Tables relationship between events and photos is one-to-many. For one event we can have many photos.

With first query I obtain all events from my db. With second query I need to obtain output for each result of first query event's photos.

I need to use only MySQL module.

Thanks.

Comment: A couple of table structures would be useful. How are the tables related?

Comment: Thanks @bjones I add required information on question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sequential query execution in NodeJS you will need to **execute next query in the success callback of previous** one, thus it would be sequential.

<kbd>Good to know ></kbd> To avoid [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) there is very useful [**async**](https://github.com/caolan/async) library where you can use [**waterfall**](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback) or [**series**](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) workflow to avoid nesting callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the result of first query, use the recursive function to fire the second query and every time you call that function you can pass the events value one by one.

Comment: Ok @Viddesh. So I need to loop second query while I don't execute it for all results of first query?

Comment: You need to fire second query for every event. Only thing you need to do is give the event in where clause of second query for every iteration till the end of events.